# RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label

Tags: python, django, sqlite

This question resulted from a suggestion to my original issue of getting Local day from a database that is storing things as UTC located [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986473/django-and-time-zones-database-storing-in-utc-but-writing-regular-python-to-try)

I had an issue with getting some UTC as local time values from a database in my django app as I was doing it be 'hand' in my script, someone in that issue (located here) suggested I try running the script with django (reworking to use the django ORM) decent idea but then get this error which is coming from my models file here:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals



from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class OnSiteLog(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

So the full error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "report_mailer_django.py", line 13, in <module>
    from covidlog.models import OnSiteLog
  File "/mnt/h/programming/web/covid19/covidlog/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 133, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 111, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I am not sure what is causing this, the file I am trying to fun should be loading django stuff just fine:

```
import django
import os
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "covid19.settings")


settings.configure()
django.setup()


# Now this script or any imported module can use any part of Django it needs.
from covidlog.models import OnSiteLog
from covidlog.models import CountTracker

def getCheckins():
   ...
   ...
```

Maybe I am missing something in my settings file?
My directory structure of my project is:

```
covid19/
    covid19/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        etc...
    covidlog/
       __init__.py
       apps.py
       forms.py
       models.py
       views.py 
       etc...
    manage.py
    report_mailer_django.py  <<- what I am trying to get to run....
```

Also my settings file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'l*s*!daf@_q&mbdp-$wq&5wq-6964c2z4s49!e9c+-az42br8f'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',    
    'covidlog.apps.CovidlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap4',
    'covid19',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'covid19.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'covidlog/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]







WSGI_APPLICATION = 'covid19.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'MST'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: "Use exactly one of either configure() or DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Not both, and not neither." Also, make sure that your root project directory is on the import path (run a shell and try importing `covid19.settings`). Finally, you must change your `SECRET_KEY` setting now that you've exposed it on this site.

Comment: Ahh okay, I did all the above, in fact the issue was just sticking to os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "covid19.settings")
 and not having the settings.configure().  If I just had the settings.configure it would still fail. So good call thanks!